# Do Mini-Sentry Guns count for the Gun Down achievement?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

The Gun Down achievement is a Scout achievement that says:

> Destroy an active sentry gun using your pistol.

Does the sentry have to be full-sized though? Would a Mini-Sentry work too?

Comment: Related: [How do I deal with turrets as a Scout?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82471/how-do-i-deal-with-turrets-as-a-scout)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the TF2 wiki on [Obtaining Scout Achievements](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Obtaining_Scout_achievements), mini-sentries do count.  The full text from that page is quoted below, with emphasis added:

> #### Gun Down
>
> Destroy an active sentry gun using your pistol.
>
> ---
>
> **Difficulty:** Medium
>
> **How to obtain:** The safest way to take out a Sentry Gun with your Pistol is to snipe an exposed section from long-range, especially if it is unattended. A more risky method would be to attack as you would with the Scattergun, circle strafing around the Sentry Gun so it does not lock onto you. You can get assistance from other classes as long as you land the finishing hit. *Combat Mini-Sentry Guns deployed by Engineers with the Gunslinger are particularly easy to destroy.* This achievement can be obtained by using the Shortstop as well.

Comment: Okay, I just got it. I can confirm.